# User model other than AUTH_USER_MODEL in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an architectural problem. I'm using Django (with admin panel) and DRF (api with stateless authentication using JWT).

Django has Admin users represented by model which is more or less the same as default Django User Model. Admins work with Django Admin only and can't use DRF api.

DRF has API users that are allowed to use only api through DRF and can't interact with Django Admin or Django Session etc.

I know that the best approach is to use multi model inheritance, like:

```
class User(DjangoUserModel):
    pass

 class Admin(User):
      pass

 class API(User):
      pass

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "User"
```

but the problem is that, those users are completly different. Eg: API user has complex composite key as an username field which is impossible in combination to simple `Admin` username field. And many other differences. ..

The question is: may I use a user object that is not an `AUTH_USER_MODEL` instance in DRF? So `self.request.user` will store a model instance that isn't connect in any way with an `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Has any of you done something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, yes sir. You can do that. Look at the following [example](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/22):

```
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication

class AuthenticatedServiceClient:
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

class JwtServiceOnlyAuthentication(JSONWebTokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate_credentials(self, payload):
        # Assign properties from payload to the AuthenticatedServiceClient object if necessary
        return AuthenticatedServiceClient()
```

And in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': None,
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'myapp.authentication.JwtServiceOnlyAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

If you want, you can define additional `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` for your DRF. The authentication classes are just like middleware, just a queue that is populating `request.user`.

Adding your own authentication classes that are using diffrent user model from `AUTH_USER_MODEL` will work exactly as you would except.

Comment: Thanks, If you were using that approach and it worked so I'm going to use it too :-)

Comment: @Gal `authenticate_credentials` is meant to return a tuple of `(user, token)`, however your example only returns `True`, would this actually work?  p.s. boo you stole my answer :(

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Django and DRF, perhaps you can write an `APIUser` model which extends from [`AbstractBaseUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser) with your customizations, write a [custom authentication class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#example) and plug that into the [REST_FRAMEWORK.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_authentication_classes) setting.  Leave AUTH_USER_MODEL alone for the django admin.

Your custom authentication may just need to override [`authenticate_credentials`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L192) (i've referenced the TokenAuthentication class in DRF github) and return an APIUser rather than the default defined in `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`.  This will be a bit different because you're decoding a JWT, so you'll likely be extract some info from your JWT and looking up your APIUser by whatever means you need, such as your composite field.  This should result in `self.request.user` being an APIUser for your DRF API views.

You're API views should be using the rest framework's settings, and your Django admin should be using the regular django settings.  There may be some other caveats, but generally you'll be ok with just this I think.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I immediately recall is how Mongoengine used to hack the whole django authentication system. Mongoengine < 0.10 has a [django compatibility app](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/tree/0.9/mongoengine/django) that implements a crutch to store users in MongoDB and make them accessible via `self.request.user`.

It has to use a crutch, because Django Session API is opinionated and assumes that you're using AUTH_USER_MODEL, backed by SQL database for storing your users.

So, I think you should disable `SessionMiddleware` and CSRF token handling and use 2 distinct [custom authentication systems](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/) for Admin and API purposes. With TokenAuthentication or JWTAuthentication this should be doable.

[Here's another example of a project](https://github.com/BurkovBA/django-rest-framework-mongoengine-example) with DRF and Mongoengine, with a [custom implementation of TokenAuthentication](https://github.com/BurkovBA/django-rest-framework-mongoengine-example/tree/master/project/users), backed by MongoDB.